# Could one use Postgres as a document database?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2, document-database

Let's say we're building a DB for storing analytics from web sites or mobile apps. **Transactions aren't important** (it's ok to drop things) and only slow things down, supporting as many concurrent calls is, consistency can be eventual, and a **part of data is going to be unstructured** (i.e. a user can pass a random JSON blob as parameter to the analytics logging call, which we will store in the DB).

Something like Mongo would be a reasonable pick for this, as it does satisfy most of the requirements I listed above. However, one does often hear about the ability of Postgres of being customizable to fill a lot of different roles. I imagine one can disable transactions etc.

I'm not very familiar with Postgres setting, and thus I must ask: is it in fact possible to adapt Postgres to fit the requirements I listed above?

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.2 has a native `json` data type (though very limited support in terms of functions for it). And a key/value datatype named `hstore`. Both type are what the mainstream calls "NoSQL".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'd have to try it out/do some tuning to see if it meets your performance needs.  But, Postgres has built-in support for transparently storing large column values (up to 1GB) efficiently called [TOAST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/storage-toast.html) (since 7.1).  The Postgres-as-a-service provider [Heroku](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/3/14/introducing_keyvalue_data_storage_in_heroku_postgres/) takes advantaged of this to offer "document store" capabilities using their hstore unstructured text Postgres datatype - that page has example applications from hstore adopters.  As far as tuning, I think [Postgres 9.0 High Performance](http://www.postgresql.org/about/news/1249/) is good reference for someone unfamiliar with postgres to figure out where to look in the Postgres online doc by topic.  For completeness, Postgres has a [large object API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/largeobjects.html) that can handle objects up to 2GB, but this would make migrating to another RDBMS more difficult than using a transparent solution like TOAST.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at using https://www.mangodb.io/ which is a wire-compatible MongoDB to SQL proxy.